# VB.NET ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

Tags: asp.net, oracle

For the last 2 hours I was trying figure out why the parameter could not be bound (Well I know I was not using the "using" block. And I know System.Data.OracleClient is deprecated.) Please help me see what's wrong with the following code:

```
  Dim nCount As Integer


  sSQL = " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = :UID "

    Dim conn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("connString"))
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand(sSQL, conn)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    With cmd
        .Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":UID", txtUserID.Text))
    End With

    Try
        nCount = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

I have tried all variations I can find online: with or without colon in the Parameters.Add, Add or AddWithValue, Add in a parenthesis or create a new OracleParameter object then add it...Nothing seems to work.

But if I just hard-code the USER_ID in the query, remove the parameter.Add, it would return a value.

Comment: Have you tried to `OracleCommand.BindByName = True` to your OracleCommand object after you create it?

Comment: Hi Scotch, VisioStudio says "'BindByName' is not a member of 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it seems that you missed something, while experimenting with different combinations.

This variant must work:

```
Dim nCount As Integer

sSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = :UID"

Dim conn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("connString"))
conn.Open()
Dim cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand(sSQL, conn)

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

cmd.Parameters.Add("UID", OracleType.VarChar).Value = txtUserID.Text

nCount = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Please try it ...

Answer (score 3):

A HA!

`UID` is actually a reserved word in Oracle. Change your `UID` variable to something that is not a reserved word.

Comment: I have tried non-reserved word, like User_ID, still no luck :(

Comment: I guess I tap out then. I'm on mobile so I can't really do any digging or testing. Hopefully someone comes along with a fix

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort :)

Comment: +1 This solved my problem with the same error message in a C# app using DapperORM.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and at least look into ODP from Oracle.  You'll need it with Microsoft finally pulls the plus on its OracleClient.  The switch over to ODP is very easy.

In your situation, I'd leave off the parameter name.  You're binding by position anyway.

The SQL syntax is also a little different in the Microsoft implementation.  Use a ? to act as each placeholder.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter.aspx for further information.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it's not my decision to do the application-wide change. All I can do is to keep it the same way as before and make the switching over more and more impossible.